# React native trying to use navigation before mounted

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, expo, react-navigation

I get the following error:

```
ERROR  The 'navigation' object hasn't been initialized yet. 
This might happen if you don't have a navigator mounted, 
or if the navigator hasn't finished mounting. 
See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop#handling-initialization 
for more details.
```

I initially had the following:

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    ...

    useEffect(() => {
      const subscriber = auth.onAuthStateChanged((_user) => {
        if (!_user) {
          navigation.navigate('Login'); 
          ...
        }
        else {
          navigation.navigate('CoreTabs', { screen: 'Home' })
        }
      });
      return subscriber;
    },[]);
```

I adjusted my code as follows (following instructions in URL provided with error.)

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
    // const navigation = useNavigation(); // removed
    const navigationRef = useNavigationContainerRef();  // added
    ...
    useEffect(() => {
      const subscriber = auth.onAuthStateChanged((_user) => {
        if (!_user) {
          // navigation.navigate('Login'); // removed
          if (navigationRef.isReady) navigationRef.navigate('Login');  // added
        }
        else {
          ...
          navigation.navigate('CoreTabs', { screen: 'Home' }) // removed
          if (navigationRef.isReady) navigationRef.navigate('CoreTabs', { screen: 'Home' }) // added
        }
      });
      return subscriber;
    },[]);
```

However I continue to receive the error. Here's how my `NavigationContainer` is setup.

```
return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Group>
            { user && <Stack.Screen name="CoreTabs" component={CoreTabs} /> }
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} }}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={RegistrationScreen}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="Reset Password" component={ResetPasswordScreen}/>
          </Stack.Group>
          <Stack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: 'modal' }}>
            <Stack.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Edit Profile" component={ProfileEditScreen} />
          </Stack.Group>
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>  
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use the `useNavigationContainerRef` hook outside the NavigationContainer.

You can get the navigationContainerRef like this.

```
const navigationRef = useRef()

return <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>...</NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: I refactored to your suggested code; but then run into this following (new) error:  `ERROR  The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"CoreTabs","params":{"name":"Home"}} was not handled by any navigator.`

Comment: That depends on if the user variable is being set. The user variable must be a state variable so that the component rerenders and CoreTabs screen is added to the stack. I will need to see the whole code.